# file system corrupt in a virtual machine

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, filesystems, io, fsck

I have a virtual machine hosted by vmware esxi. It has been started for over 80 days. And about ten days ago, its file system got corrupted. Although I can use `fsck` to fix this file system, I am wondering what can be the root reason? It is just a virtual machine and there isn't any power off action.

BTW, that vm is not the only vmware on that host. There are several vms.

In this case, I suppose it could because of IO congestion. This machine want to flush virtual disk changes into hard disk, but there are a lot of other write actions. So its write action hangs in cache queue and get timeout later.

Is it possible?

## update: add related information

VM's OS: Centos6.9

Disk attach type: SATA with default cache strategy

fsck: Doesn't pass the following check

Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes

Pass 5: Checking group summary information

As I cannot directly access to host machine, I cannot give more information about VMWare itself, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely a problem with the underlying hardware of the VMware host server.

You have not posted any of the details of the hardware involved, the versions and build number of VMware, the OS distribution and version you're dealing with or anything else that would help find a root cause.

Comment: Thanks in advance, I will collect information and edit my question as soon as possible.

Comment: Is added information helpful?

Comment: I would suggest contacting whoever is in control of the physical hardware. This is not something you can fix.

Comment: I think so, so I just looking for some possible reasons as they may help me to argue with them :)